# Add UIView from xib to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I am making an application, and I started with a single view controller with one view inside. I made my app but I want to have multiple pages and allow the user to swipe between them. I want to use a UISCrollView. How can I set up a UIScrollView so that I can insert my already made view from the xib. I don't want to make a view programmatically because a lot of it is graphical and I don't really know what I'm doing.

Recap: UIScrollView to swipe between views I have made in xib files

Answer (score 3):

in your main view controller, add a scrollview. You can add scrollview to mainview in Xib.

In mainview controller .h file add a property , then load programmatically your views and add to scroll. Set each view position. Set scrollview reference in your main xib properly.

```
    @property(nonatomic, weak) IBoutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

UIView *view1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myViewXib1" owner:self options:nil];
UIView *view2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myViewXib2" owner:self options:nil];
UIView *view3 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myViewXib3" owner:self options:nil];

CGRect frame;
frame = view1.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
view1.frame = frame;

frame = view2.frame;
frame.origin.x = view1.frame.size.width + view1.frame.origin.x ;
view2.frame = frame;

frame = view3.frame;
frame.origin.x = view2.frame.size.width + view2.frame.origin.x;
view3.frame = frame;
[scrolView addSubView:view1];
[scrolView addSubView:view2];
[scrolView addSubView:view3];
```

Comment: I copied part of your code to fit with my one view xib, but I'm getting errors on nearly every line. As I said below I'm really inexperienced so if you could help me with what to change/where to put it, that would be great! -----  
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBoutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

UIView *clockView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BarsViewController" owner:self options:nil];

CGRect frame;
frame = view1.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
view1.frame = frame;

Comment: I gave an example for put view in front of one, please copy your code and I can help more.

Comment: @property(nonatomic, weak) IBoutlet UIScrollView *scrollView; UIView *clockView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BarsViewController" owner:self options:nil];  [scrollView addSubView:clockView];

Comment: I'm going to talk you through what I'm doing because it's not working. Firstly I drag a UIScrollView from the object library onto my viewController.xib. I then put this outside the brackets in my viewController.h file: @property(nonatomic, weak) IBoutlet UIScrollView *scrollView; After that, I put this in the viewController.m file, in viewDidLoad: UIView *clockView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BarsViewController" owner:self options:nil]; It comes up with the warning "Incompatible pointer types initializing 'UIView *' with an expression of type 'NSArray *'"

Comment: Then I put this underneath: CGRect frame;
    frame = clockView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    clockView.frame = frame; No errors. Under that, I put : [scrollView addSubView:clockView]; and got the error "Unknown receiver 'scrollView'; did you mean 'UIScrollView'?" Lastly, I connected the UIScrollView in my xib to the property '*scrollView".

Comment: Obviously it failed to build. If you could help me out and be really clear of what to do and where to do it, that would be really helpful! I am so inexperienced with all of this so it is like a completely different language to me. I find it astounding how difficult and complex it is to just have a swipe between two views!!

Answer (score 0):

Declare IBOutlet in your view controller to point to that view.

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBoutlet UIView *myView;
```

Connect your view from xib to myView.

Load your xib in the view controller viewDidLoad method

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myViewXib" owner:self options:nil];
```

Then add myView to your scrollview.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to all this; do I need to make a new view controller to add a UIScrollView? Sorry, it probably sounds stupid but if you could be really specific otherwise I'm quite lost. Thanks!

Comment: You can use your single view controller to manage your scrollview. You can add the scroll view to your view controller's view either in xib or even in your code in viewDidLoad. You can refer to scrollview guide from Apple if you need more info https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH101-SW1